# What does it mean when a drill says it is 3/8", and where do I get bits and extensions for it?

Tags: drill

Bought a Ryboi D42 3/8" drill.

A bit of confusion first, when it states it's a 3/8" is that saying the diameter or circumference of the drill hole is 3/8"? or something else?

This drill is very good for it's price but I don't know what to do for bits and other extensions. Do I have to buy specialized parts/bits from Ryboi or can I use any bit that fits the 3/8" diameter/circumference?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

3/8 inch is the maximum shaft diameter that fits in the chuck.  That doesn't mean you can't drill larger holes, but the part the drill chuck grips has to be this size or smaller. (Some higher-powered drills have half -inch chucks.)

Bits should be widely available -- home centers, hardware stores, most places that sell tools.

Comment: You can get bits that much larger that have the smaller shaft. You just want to be sure you are not over taxing your drill when you do this. If you buy a 1.25" Paddle bit for your Drill, just take it slow.

Comment: Wonderful! so it doesn't have to be the Ryobi brand any 3/8" diameter drill bit/extensions will work? I guess that was a silly question but I didn't want to buy something and not have it work. Thank you